# Cannot set resolution higher than 1280×1024 in Deus Ex: Human Revolution

Tags: technical-issues, deus-ex-human-revolution

I am having some issues with Deus Ex: HR. I just recently got a new computer and when I installed DE:HR again through Steam (and reinstalled it now) I can't set the resolution higher than 1280×1024, even when I set the aspect ratio to 16:9.  Now the TV I am using as a monitor whenever I set to a resolution that has 1280 in it will go off the screen. But I can set things to 1920×1080 and have done so before. Now the weird thing is that in the setup Deus Ex will not let me set the resolution higher than 1280×1024 and I don't know why.

If you know something please let me know

My computer specs:

- AMD Phenom x6 1055t 2.8 GHz hex-core
- 8 GB of ram
- AMD Radeon HD 6870 1 GB
- ...and I think those are the important parts for this question.

Edit: After looking around the internet I have found no answer to this yet. I really want to play so if anyone has an answer please let me know :).

Comment: Oh. thanks for editing and clearing that up. I like the way it has been re worded. That is a great feature!

Comment: What kind of connection do you use between your TV and graphics card? HDMI? DVI? VGA? Does your TV have PC drivers? It looks to me like your the game doesn't know which resolutions are supported by your TV.

Comment: Have you tried changing the launch option of the game to "-w <width> -h <heigh>" ?

Comment: It is connected to my TV through HDMI. My TV should have PC drivers as it can run other games such as Skyrim, League of Legends, and Burnout Paradise all in 1080.

Comment: do you have the latest drivers for your video card?

Comment: Well I did when I had this problem. There has been an update do my drivers since then. However, I installed it and it caused problems with Skyrim. So I went back to the older driver in order to play Skyrim. I don't know if it solves the Deus Ex problem either.

Comment: TV model is also important in the question. Some displays can change resolution onto a virtual one, which will go offscreen, but if you bring the mouse pointer, the displayed screen area will scroll.